# Getting object's address from its pointer to member variable

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to get the actual object's pointer from a pointer to member variable.

Yes, I know there is `offsetof` macro, but it needs the name of a member variable, not the pointer to the member variable.

It actually was not difficult to implement but I'm not sure it's 100% standard conformant code.

```
template <class T, class M, M T::*Ptr>
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t offset_to_member()
{
  return static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)->*Ptr)))
         - static_cast<char*>(nullptr);
}

template <class T, class M, M T::*Ptr>
constexpr T* object_ptr_from_member(M *__ptr)
{
  // reinterpret_cast is not allowed in constexpr function
  return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(
           static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(__ptr)) - offset_to_member<T, M, Ptr>()));
}
```

result : http://ideone.com/1Z2nIR

Clang++ and g++ both compiled the code without any warning, but I need more than 'it seems working'.

Is the code valid in c++11 standard?

Comment: And how does *this* not need the "name" of the member?

Comment: There is no standard-conformant way to do this. Compilers don't warn you because you are telling them to shut up and compile (casts).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you implement `object_ptr_from_member` with `offsetof`? It's the given condition. Why would i ask the question if I could've changed everything as I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static_cast<T*>(nullptr)->*Ptr
```

Equivalent to `(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr)).*Ptr` according to [expr.mptr.oper]/3, which triggers undefined behavior.
 And not `constexpr` (precisely because of UB) - [expr.const]/2:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the
>   evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would
>   evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - an operation that would have undefined behavior.

Comment: I didn't think that the first statement actually dereference the nullptr. If it triggers UB, then there's no 100% standard-conformant implementation of `offsetof` besides the compiler extension, right?

Comment: @kukyakya: Yes, `offsetof` cannot be implemented in standards-conformant code. But no worries, the implementation is free to do any magic neccessary to get things done.

Comment: @kukyakya GCC uses an intrinsic, namely `__builtin_offsetof`.